# How do you pass results from a JSON array into into a multidimensional array?

Tags: android, json, list, multidimensional-array

I am a little new to android/java. I am trying to pass JSON values into a list and then into a multidimensional array.  I am not having much success.

2 questions, 
1) How would I load all of the variables in a json array into children[][]? 
2) How do you view children[][] in Log.i

Herei s my code:

```
List<String> cList = new ArrayList<String>();
String customer_name, customer_title, customer_postal_code, customer_city, customer_state, customer_street_address;   
ArrayList<String> cTitle, cClubName, cPostalCode, cCity, cState, cStreet = new ArrayList<String>();    
public String[][] children = null;
```

//... onCreate method, HTTP Connection, StringBuilder, etc. These work fine...
// Pass data into array

```
try{
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
    JSONObject jData=null;


String[][] children = new String[jArray.length()][6];

    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){


            jData = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

            customer_name=jData.getString("customer_name");     
            Log.i("JSON ", "customer_name LOG " + customer_name);
            cList.add(customer_name);

            customer_title=jData.getString("event_title");
            Log.i("JSON ", "customer_title LOG " + customer_title);
            cList.add(customer_title);

            customer_street_address=jData.getString("customer_street_address");
            Log.i("JSON ", "customer_Id LOG " + customer_street_address);
            cList.add(customer_street_address);


            customer_city=jData.getString("customer_city");
            Log.i("JSON ", "customer_city LOG " + customer_city);
            cList.add(customer_city);



            customer_state=jData.getString("customer_state");   
            Log.i("JSON ", "customer_state LOG " + customer_state);
            cList.add(customer_state);


            customer_postal_code=jData.getString("customer_postal_code");               
            Log.i("JSON ", "customer_postal_code LOG " + customer_postal_code);
            cList.add(customer_postal_code);

            for(int ic = 0; ic < cList.size(); ic++) {      
                Log.i("jData ", "length " + jData.length());

                children[i][ic] = (String) cList.get(ic);

            }

            Log.i("Child Array", "Children array LOG " + children);




    }


    }catch(JSONException e1){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No customers Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }catch (ParseException e1){
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

Comment: Can you get an example of a json? I will try to get you more flexible and good looking solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your code correctly you don't need cList.
Something like that should do the work

```
String[][] children = new String[jArray.length()][6];

    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){

            jData = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

            customer_name=jData.getString("customer_name");     
            Log.i("JSON ", "customer_name LOG " + customer_name);
            children[i][0] = customer_name;


            customer_title=jData.getString("event_title");
            Log.i("JSON ", "customer_title LOG " + customer_title);
            children[i][1] = event_title;

            customer_street_address=jData.getString("customer_street_address");
            Log.i("JSON ", "customer_Id LOG " + customer_street_address);
            children[i][2] = customer_street_address;

            customer_city=jData.getString("customer_city");
            Log.i("JSON ", "customer_city LOG " + customer_city);
            children[i][3] = customer_city;

            customer_state=jData.getString("customer_state");   
            Log.i("JSON ", "customer_state LOG " + customer_state);
            children[i][4] = customer_state;


            customer_postal_code=jData.getString("customer_postal_code");               
            Log.i("JSON ", "customer_postal_code LOG " + customer_postal_code);
            children[i][5] = customer_postal_code;
    }
```

Make sure your JSON data is well-formed to avoid exceptions. 
To view children[][] you can just iterate twice on your multidimentional array and do Log.i("MyTag", "Value: " + children[i][j]);

Answer (score 0):

```
String[][] data = new String[jsonArray.length][];

for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length; i++){
     data[i] = ((ArrayList)jsonArray).get(i).toArray(new String[((ArrayList)jsonArray).get(i).size])
}
```

for printing in log

```
Log.d("array", data);
```